# TIN Output empty raster and corrupted Triangulation network

Tags: qgis, point, interpolation, tin, linux-mint

In Qgis:
I've got a point shape (EPSG:3398) with some height info and want to create a TIN interpolated raster with the Qgis TIN-Interpolation tool.
But after running there was a raster created, which is invisible on the map and with impossible values and the the triangulation network only was made for the southern points like seen in the screenshot.

[image: No Raster and corrupted TIN network]

The point shape doesn't contain corrupted data.

[image: Attribute table and properties]

The settings of the TIN tool - no error message while running

[image: My inputs for the TIN tool]

The project EPSG is the same than the point shape.
I'm running Q-GIS 3.12.3 on Linux Mint 19.2 (via apt).

What I've tried yet:
Reproject the Point shape to different EPSGs;
Change raster resolution
...with no success.

Comment: Seems like you are doing it correct. The Interpolation attribute needs to be numeric which it is and using RD/83 / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4 should work fine. The extent is I quess your view extent? If you want I can give it a go.

Comment: As extend I've tried the layer extend as well as the view extend. I've added a drive Link to my post with the shape file. I'll take it off as soon as you've got the data.

Comment: David I took it of the drive. I will take a look at it.

Comment: It seems that there was a problem with the shapefile. I created a new one and it seems to work. The Tin Interpolation is now on 20% so I hope it will finish in the next hour. If this works correctly, I will write an answer and post the new shapefile + Raster in a wetransfer link. I will also write what I exactly did to overcome the problem and what might have caused the issue.

Comment: The TIN Interpolation is now finished after several hours, however, it still returns 1.79769e+308 values.

Comment: hmmm That's weird. Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

David it took some time, but I managed to get the correct data for you using the TIN Interpolation Tool. However, there is a catch. During my research I came across this article from September 2019 on Github where somebody had the same problem having e+ values using QGIS 3.8.3.

https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/31970

In this article the statement was made:

> The extent of the output and the pixels size are likely to not match
>   perfectly, so there must be some rounding......

So I started testing your shapefile and your Tiefe NN seemed 162.600. But it constantly returned 1.79769e+ 308. I used the layers extent. When I exported it as a .CSV file it created an error. When I exported it as .XLSX and imported it again, the Tiefe NN was not 162.600 but 162.599 (with really a lot of extra decimals). So I created a new attribute field with one decimal, and my first test returned fine as you can see. I tested the most southern part (1341 features).

[image]

So your initial question, your raster was invisible and the values impossible, is solved.
But now your real problem. When I expend the test with more points (1809 features) this result was returned.

[image]

The reason for this is also explained in that article.

> To honor the pixel size (ex. 0.25) the tool could simply round the
>   xmin/ymin coordinates DOWN to the nearest whole pixel size and the
>   xmax/ymax UP to the nearest whole pixel size. When doing this manually
>   through the extent parameter, the values are not honored. Padding with
>   extra pixels (rows/columns) is not possible either.

However, this new problem does not really provide you with a satisfying solution. But there is hope. Two days ago a new comment was placed on this article by Alexbruy with following link and title:

**Fix calculating raster size in the TIN and IDW algorithms to maintain accurate pixel size**
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36822

Here it is stated that the issue was fixed and is added to the Qgis 3.14.0 milestone. On the [QGIS.org](https://www.qgis.org/nl/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#location-of-prereleases-nightly-builds) website it is stated that 3.14.0 is planned to be released on the **19th of June 2020.**

I hope that this would solve your problem completely.

In the following wetransferlink I have the shapefile that I made from your original shapefile. Instead of using Tiefe NN use Hight (I know it is Height in proper English).

[Later EDIT by GISGUILD]

Since I understand that you need the data I made a Interpolated TIN raster for you in ArcGIS PRO. I will add this raster to the Wetransfer link. Simply browse to the RASTER folder and drop the entire tin raster folder in QGIS.

Good luck!

https://we.tl/t-JSRNiAfaVt

[image]

Comment: Can I remove the Wetransferlink?